# attachment page template? only show attachments for current post?

Tags: functions, templates, attachments

hey guys,
didn't know that, but the attachement page (i'm using attachment.php as template) is actually looping through ALL ever uploaded attachments to my blog!

I just want to use it in order to view the images of a gallery etc. So I just want to loop through the images that are specific to the current post.

Any idea how to solve that?

attachment.php

```
<div class="posts-container">   

    <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'attachment' ); ?>

</div> <!-- posts-container -->
```

loop-attachment.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                    <div class="entry">

                        <div class="entry-attachment">

<?php if ( wp_attachment_is_image() ) :
    $attachments = array_values( get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->post_parent, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID' ) ) );
    foreach ( $attachments as $k => $attachment ) {
        if ( $attachment->ID == $post->ID )
            break;
    }
    $k++;
    // If there is more than 1 image attachment in a gallery
    if ( count( $attachments ) > 1 ) {
        if ( isset( $attachments[ $k ] ) )
            // get the URL of the next image attachment
            $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $attachments[ $k ]->ID );
        else
            // or get the URL of the first image attachment
            $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $attachments[ 0 ]->ID );
    } else {
        // or, if there's only 1 image attachment, get the URL of the image
        $next_attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url();
    }
?>
                        <div class="attachment">
                            <!-- <a href="<?php echo $next_attachment_url; ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>" rel="attachment"> -->

                            <?php
                            $attachment_width  = apply_filters( 'attachment_width', 1068 );
                            $attachment_height = apply_filters( 'attachment_height', 1068 );
                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, array( $attachment_width, $attachment_height ) ); // filterable image width with, essentially, no limit for image height.
                        ?>
                            <!-- </a> -->

                            <div class="nav-previous">
                                <?php previous_image_link( false, '&nbsp;' ); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-next">
                                <?php next_image_link( false, '&nbsp;' ); ?>
                            </div>

                        </div>

<?php endif; ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-attachment -->

                        <div class="entry-caption">

                        <?php if ( !empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) the_excerpt(); ?>

                        </div>

                    </div><!-- entry -->

                </article><!-- post -->

<?php //comments_template(); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: I think that is theme depended, what theme are you using, or even better post your  attachement.php file's code.

Comment: Updated my question with the template code!

Comment: why did my question get a down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attachment.php` is a specific template in the [WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). WordPress uses it for a specific purpose, and the default Loop just won't do what you're claiming it's doing. (The behavior you're describing would be analogous to the `single.php` template file looping through all Posts.)

I'm guessing your `attachment.php` template file has a custom Loop. As Baiternet asked above, can you post or link the markup of your `attachment.php` template file?

Comment: that is correct but its not really an answer and should be a comment.

Comment: @Baiternet: I'm hoping I can revise my answer once the code is posted.